# Reinstall openssh with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I want to install openssh using cygwin. I ran `ssh-host-config`, and I was guided through a text menu. I entered what I found on a webpage had to be entered, until I came to this point: `Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon: [] binmode ntsec` , where I accidentally hit enter before I typed it all in (yes, clumsy, fat fingers). I am not aware of the significance of `binmode ntsec`, but I didn't want to take any chances, so I figured I'd just delete everything and start over.

Running `ssh-host-config` again, however, did not behave as it did the first time. It skipped that one query. I then deleted the entire cygwin folder and reinstalled from scratch, but `ssh-host-config` keeps saying that `Sshd service is already installed`, and I don't get the chance to enter this `binmode ntsec` name. I found threads with tips how to remove cygwin completely, but something seems to remain behind, because `ssh-host-config` never behaves like it did the first time.

I have three questions:

1.) Why does `ssh-host-config` not behave like it did the first time, even though I delete and reinstall cygwin? It must have a memory outside of the cygwin folder?

2.) In which config file is that 'value of CYGWIN' = `binmode ntsec` stored?

3.) What is its significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably reading a too old suggestion.
There is no need to set those parameters in the CYGWIN variable for sshd usage

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html

> Obsolete options
>
> Certain CYGWIN options available in past releases have been removed
> over time for one reason or another. These obsolete options are listed
> below.
>
> (no)binmode - This option has been removed because all file opens
> default to binary mode, unless the open mode has been specified
> explicitly in the open(2) call.
> ...
> (no)ntsec - This option has been removed in favor of the per-mount
> option "acl"/"noacl". For more information, read the documentation in
> the section called “The Cygwin Mount Table”.

Additional info:
As SSHD is set as windows service, the value of CYGWIN variable, if used, is stored in the windows register at
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cygsshd`